# When do symbols for functions bind in Python? Is forward declaration possible?

Tags: python, syntax, forward-declaration

Suppose we have a hash table that maps strings to functions. In my example I'll call it `COMMANDS`. If I place the definition for some function (let's call it `cmd_add`) *after* the hash table that maps it to a string, and then I attempt to invoke it, I get an error:

```
COMMANDS = {'add': cmd_add}

def cmd_add():
  print 'ADD'

COMMANDS['add']()

# NameError: name 'cmd_add' is not defined
```

Now notice that if I simply move the function definition to before the definition of `COMMANDS`, it works out just fine:

```
def cmd_add():
  print 'ADD'

COMMANDS = {'add': cmd_add}

COMMANDS['add']()

# NO ERROR!
```

Why is this true? Is there something about Python binding that I do not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that Python is a dynamic language, even though cmd_add is a reference to a function in your source there is nothing stopping it from referring to a different object at different times.

Python will creating the binding as the interpreter passes the line where the function is defined and it will reference that function until you delete the reference or rebind it to something else

Comment: However, JavaScript is a dynamic language -- and yet has forward references for `FunctionDeclaration` constructs and `var`. (That is, this answer needs clarification as this is not an inherent property of all dynamic languages.)

Comment: Ah, thank you, I can see now how it would not make sense from a Pythonic perspective for the first example to work.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the module is interpreted from top to bottom. In your first snippet, it hasn't seen `cmd_add` yet, so it throws a `NameError`

You can do it like your second snippet, or something like this:

```
COMMANDS = {}

def cmd_add():
    print 'ADD'

def register_commands():
    COMMANDS.update({'add': cmd_add})

register_commands()
```

Or you could get fancy and wrap `cmd_add` with a decorator that registers it in the `COMMANDS`

```
COMMANDS = {}

# command decorator to register command functions
class command(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __call__(self, func):
        COMMANDS[self.name] = func
        return func

@command('add')
def cmd_add():
    print 'ADD'

COMMANDS['add']()
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Python script, the expressions are evaluated from top to bottom, therefore you can't reference a function *before* defining it.